# Remove Grafana and Alertmanager while installing kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kube-prometheus-stack

I want to install the `kube-prometheus-stack` (https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus) but exclude `Grafana` and `Alertmanager` from the helm install as I am installing them separately.

I would like to install only the following components:

- Prometheus Operator
- Prometheus
- Prometheus node-exporter
- Prometheus Adapter for Kubernetes Metrics APIs
- kube-state-metrics

I tried to create a `values.yaml` file locally and install using helm chart but I am not successful doing so.

What's the best way to do this?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Those are subcharts(dependencies) in `kube-prometheus-stack` helm chart. usually all subcharts have something like this:

```yaml
## subchartname:
##    enabled: true
grafana:
  enabled: false
```

and also You can check `dependencies` section in `Chart.yaml` file and see what is the condition key to enable/disable a dependency.

Links:

- [grafana condition key in `Chart.yaml` file](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/Chart.yaml#L53)
- [option to disable grafana in values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L754-L755)

Comment: I actually created a `override.yaml` file and made `grafana` and `alertmanager` enabled: false. I passed this file while installing the chart. Worked fine! Thanks.